# Include one page/post into query which is already returning posts

Tags: wp-query, query

I have my news query which is on my index file.

I want to include a post into this query which is infact a page.

Is there anyway to do this?

```
<?php query_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged
)); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

My page id is 6417 - If I use post__in then that is the only thing that shows.

Can anyone advice please, do I need to do with a meta query?

Thanks

Comment: First of all don't use `query_post`, for details see this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts..
Then to include page in the query add the args `post_type => array( 'post', 'page' )`. For more details check http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters

Comment: @Maruit query post is my main loop so this is OK. And I know how to query and array of post types, how ever I just need to query one page, not all of them. Thanks

Comment: Even for your main loop, you should **not** use `query_posts()`. Filter the query at `pre_get_posts` instead.

Comment: OK cool, but still none of the above is getting me closer to solving my problem of simply showing one page in my news feed. Thanks

Comment: and also why does this image say query post for main loop only which is what I am doing, is this diagram wrong? http://www.rarst.net/images/query_functions.png

Comment: You can try getting that specific page by using get_post( $page_id ) and add this once the loop gets over or something. I dont think there is any way to inject a specific page into the news query.

Comment: @Subharanjan ok thanks I thought that my be the case as I could not find anything.

Comment: That question/answer doesn't address the inherent problems with `query_posts()` and why `pre_get_posts` should be used instead. [This one does](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-to-use-wp-query-query-posts-and-pre-get-posts).

Answer (score 1):

And here is the correct implementation:

Register the `category` taxonomy for the `page` post-type:

```
function wpse121285_add_category_to_pages() {  
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'wpse121285_add_category_to_pages' );
```

Add the appropriate category term to the desired page.

Then modify the default `$wp_query` object at `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse121285_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    // Main query for the blog posts index
    // Note that you can use most/any contextual
    // conditional here, depending on your needs
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
        $query->set( 'category_name', 'news' );
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse121285_pre_get_posts' );
```

Leave the default Loop markup alone:

```
// No query_posts() needed here!
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.. probably !!

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        global $post;
        if ( some_condition ) {
            $page_id = 6417; // This is the ID of the page to be included
            $post = get_post( $page_id );
        }else{
            the_post(); // END custom first post
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured out a solution my self.

I used this function to add categories to my news feed.

```
function add_category_to_pages() {  
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');  
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_category_to_pages' );
```

I then found my page I wanted an selected my news category and then ammended the query...

```
<?php query_posts(array(

    'post_type' => array('post','page'),
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'category_name' => 'news'

)); if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```